# Javascript Make Form Appear

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code (Javascript and HTML):

```
<div id="welcomename">
<h1>Welcome! What's your name?</h1>
<input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="Your name here!" id="name"/>
<input type="button" onclick="clicked();" value="I'm ready!"/>
</div>
<br>

<div id="welcomehowareyou">
<h1>How are you today, ?</h1>
<input type="text" class="form" name="howareyou" id="howareyou"/>
<input type="button" onclick="clicked();" value="I'm ready!"/>
</div>
</div>
<br>

<script>
function clicked() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
if(confirm('Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!'))
{
document.getElementById('welcomehowareyou').innerHTML = 'How are you today, ' + name + '?';
document.getElementById('welcomename').style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Basically in the first form, the user enters there name, then hits submit and a Javascript confirmation appears, saying `'How are you today, ' + name + '?'`

When they click ok to that prompt, how do I make the form '**welcomehowareyou**' appear (not in an alert)?

One more thing, where it says `'How are you today, ?'` how do I make the name appear there which the user entered in the form '**welcomename**'?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean form, not forum.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this with the following code:

```
**<div id="hiddenDiv" style="visibility:hidden;">**
<h1 id="welcomehowareyou">How are you today, ?</h1>
<h1>How are you today, ?</h1>
<input type="text" class="form" name="howareyou" id="howareyou"/>
<input type="button" onclick="clicked();" value="I'm ready!"/>
**</div>**
<br>

<script>
function clicked() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
if(confirm('Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!'))
{
document.getElementById('welcomehowareyou').innerHTML = 'How are you today, ' + name + '?';
document.getElementById('welcomename').style.display = "none";
**document.getElementById("hiddenDiv").style.visibility ="visible";**
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID should be on the `<h1>`, not the `<div>`. Otherwise, when you use `.innerHTML`, you'll replace everything in the DIV, not just that message.

```
<div>
<h1 id="welcomehowareyou">How are you today, ?</h1>
<input type="text" class="form" name="howareyou" id="howareyou"/>
<input type="button" onclick="clicked();" value="I'm ready!"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I've made the appropriate change.

Comment: Just a question, how do I hide 'welcomehowareyou' until the user clicks ok on the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Try this peice of JavaScript:

```
<script>
function clicked() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

if(confirm('Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!')) {
    document.getElementById('welcomehowareyou').firstElementChild.innerHTML = 'How are you today, ' + name + '?';
    document.getElementById('welcomename').style.display = "none";
}

}
</script>
```